# Display a JPanel on full screen

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

Hello I have a JPanel who contained a JTable and a TextField. I want that the display screen is displayed in full screen because  in my case it appears half of the screen.here's not a parameter of screen size that I have to specify or change?

This is the result:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmUZX.png]

```
 public MainWindow()
 {
super("Fullscreen");
getContentPane().setPreferredSize(      

Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
pack();
setResizable(false);
show();
```

Comment: Post the code that you have tried .

Comment: i added it but i don't want where i put it

Comment: Will you post the code in which you have added the jpanel ,also this issue look like some layout issue

Answer (score 2):

```
getContentPane().setPreferredSize(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
pack();
setResizable(false);
show();
```

A few problems with the code:

1. You can't just set the size of the content pane to be the size of the screen. A frame has decorations (title bar, borders) that need to be considered.
2. The order of pack() and setResizable(...) is wrong. The pack() statement needs to be invoked AFTER you add components to the screen and after you set the resizable property of the frame.
3. The `show()` method is not used anymore.

If you just want to display the frame maximized the code is:

```
frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
frame.setResizable(false);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

I suggest you look at the `FrameDemo` found in the Swing tutorial on [How to Make Frames](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html) for working code to get you started. I don't know where you found your current code example but I would lose the code and learn how to do Swing coding properly. Bookmark the Swing tutorial for examples of all Swing basics.

Comment: the frist code genere an error getContendPane() is undefined for the type maybe because i'm using JPanel not JFrame

Comment: @Georgio yes, I told you the code was wrong and then gave you the proper code to use.

Comment: but i'm using a JPanel not a JFrame

Comment: You are adding a JPanel to a JFrame. If you make the frame the maximum size of the window then the layout manager will make the panel the maximum size of the frame. Using Swing is about learning how to use the proper layout manager to achieve your layout.

Comment: u must declare variable frame?

Comment: @Georgio, Why? Did you do that when you used the pack() and setResizable(...) methods? You need to learn Swing basics especially how layout managers work. The problem with your code is how you build the panel. So start by downloading the `ListDemo` code found in the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html). Run the code as is. Then add the `setExtendedState(...)` method to the code an retest to see the difference. Then you need to fix your code to use proper layout managers.

Answer (score 0):

the frame has a setSize method, where you can pass the dimension you want.
to get the screen size you can use

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()
```

Comment: I'm using a JPanel

Answer (score 0):

setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score -1):

Add a `ComponentListener` with `componentResized()` method. When the size changed make equal your JPanel's and JTable's size to JFrame's size. And also, while defining JPanel and JTable make their sizes' equal to JFrame's size.

Comment: Don't do this! if you make the JTable's size equal to the frame's size, there will be no room for any other components (like the TextField). You should use the appropriate LayoutManager to automatically size the children when the frame changes size.

Comment: As I understand, the TextField is inside JTable. Am I wrong?

Comment: no the TextFiled is not inside the JTable on my post i show the result on an image